# C convert for loop into a while loop and recursion

Tags: c, loops, recursion, syntax

I'm doing another exercise and I have to :

> "Write a recursive function to print all solution to the eight queens chess problem, return the number of solutions and the function prototype must be : *int function(void)*

To work around the *no argument* rule I used *static* variables.

I've done it (with google's help), and it works, but they don't allow to use `for` loops and for some reason I can't manage to convert the last two `for` loops to `while` loops.

It' driving me crazy, it should be easy! I think it's the recursion that mess it up...

Here's the working function :

```
int function()
{
    static int count = 0;
    static int col = 0;
    const int n = 8;
    static int hist[8] = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
    int i1 = 0;

    if (col == n) {
        count++;
        while (i1++ < n)
        {
            putchar('0' + hist[i1-1] + 1);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < col && !(hist[j] == i || (hist[j] - i) == col - j || -(hist[j] - i) == col - j); j++);

        if (j < col) {
            continue;
        }
        hist[col] = i;
        col++;
        function();
        col--;  
    }
    return count;
}
```

And I tried to convert the two last `for` loops to `while` loops like this :

```
int i = 0;
while (i < n)
{
    int j = 0;
    while (j < col && !(hist[j] == i || (hist[j] - i) == col - j || -(hist[j] - i) == col - j))
    {
        j++;
    }

    if (j < col) {
        continue;
    }
    hist[col] = i;

    col++;
    function();
    col--;
    i++;
}
```

But it doesn't work, is there more the for loops than it seems ? I'm new to recursion, I thought I got it but it seems I was wrong...

Comment: `for` to `while` conversion part seems correct to me. Is that the only thing you changed ?

Comment: yes it is all in the question, you can try it, the first works but the second doesn't :/

Comment: So, you have changed only the last `for` loop leaving rest as is. I hope you have kept the return statement.

Comment: yes I kept everything and tried to change the for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code and found the problem. It is with the line

```
if (j < col) {
    continue;
}
```

since this isn't a `continue` statement that goes to a `for` loop, you have to increment `i` in this condition as well.

```
if (j < col) {
    i++;      // add this line
    continue;
}
```

Comment: that's what StackExchange is about :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the first loop to

```
    while(i++<n)
```

and it works fine.